# Splitting string in for loop in python

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to iterate over a list of rows in a table and do modify a string in one of the columns:

```
# python 2.7
import csv
import re

with open('root_diff.txt', 'rU') as dmr:
    coordinates_tsv = csv.reader(dmr, delimiter='\t')
    coordinates_list = [row for row in coordinates_tsv]

    for row in coordinates_list:
        cut = re.split(':|-|r', row[3])
        print cut[1]
```

But I get the following error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

The string in `row[3]` looks something like this: `chr1:594572-598657`.
I want to split it so it looks like this: `['ch', '1', '594572', '598657']`, and do something with the second and third numbers.

Comment: You do *not* need to create `coordinates_list`; just loop directly over `coordinates_tsv`: `for row in coordinates_tsv`.

Comment: What line throws the exception? Can you include the *full* traceback please?

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious now! Although that wasn't the cause of the error I'm getting

Comment: That is why I posted that as a comment, not an answer. Without the traceback, I can only guess which one of the two lines is the problem here.

Comment: Do you have any blank lines in the file? Or a rows that doesn't have 4th column? If `row[3]` doesn't match your pattern, you won't get an error - I suspect this is your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be at least *one* value for `row[3]` that doesn't contain any of the characters to split on.

To debug, catch the `IndexError` and print `cut` and / or `row[3]` to see what is going on:

```
try:
    print cut[1]
except IndexError:
    print '-- unexpected input --', row[3]
```

If this is the header, skip it with `next()`:

```
with open('root_diff.txt', 'rU') as dmr:
    coordinates_tsv = csv.reader(dmr, delimiter='\t')

    next(coordinates_tsv, None)  # skip first row, the header

    for row in coordinates_tsv:
```

Note that in theory, it could also still be the *previous* line that is throwing this exception; you didn't share the traceback in your post. A blank line or a line with fewer columns would lead to an `IndexError` for `row[3]`. A blank line gives an empty list, for example.

Comment: There is a header, I deleted it & it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!